# How do I store clap::ArgMatches in a struct?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm trying to store `clap::ArgMatches` in a struct like so:

```
struct Configurator {
    cli_args: ArgMatches,
    root_directory: String
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/configurator.rs:5:15
  |
5 |     cli_args: ArgMatches,
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
  |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
  |
4 | struct Configurator<'a> {
5 |     cli_args: ArgMatches<'a>,
  |
```

I tried the suggested solution that is given in the error output, but that appears to cause different errors.

Here's a little more context:

```
extern crate clap;
use clap::{Arg, App, ArgMatches};

struct Configurator {
    cli_args: ArgMatches,
    root_directory: String
}

impl Configurator {
    pub fn build() -> Configurator {
        let configurator = Configurator {};

        // returns ArgMatches apparently 
        let cli_args = App::new("Rust Web Server")
            .version("0.0.1")
            .author("Blaine Lafreniere <brlafreniere@gmail.com>")
            .about("A simple web server built in rust.")
            .arg(Arg::with_name("root_dir")
                .short("r")
                .long("root_dir")
                .value_name("ROOT_DIR")
                .help("Set the root directory that the web server will serve from.")
                .takes_value(true))
            .get_matches();
        
        configurator.cli_args = cli_args;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [error[E0106\]: missing lifetime specifier (despite it being set)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217705/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster tried the solution suggested in that link and no, it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to show how you're constructing `clap::App` and also what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Shepmaster Here's the deal: if I knew what was going on and how to fix this code, and why it was different than the link you just linked, I wouldn't be here on stackoverflow asking questions.

Comment: Just a precision: `App::new()` returns a `App` struct; then you can parse the actual cli arguments with `your_app_instance.get_matches()`, which returns a `ArgMatches` instance.

Comment: Adding the lifetime specifier as the error message suggests seems to work just fine [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20d2194069ef53865e8f1d426a4297ca). Can you please explain what exactly was not working for you?

Comment: @yolenoyer I've added some more context

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, you have to add named lifetime specifiers to `Configurator`. This is because `ArgMatches` holds references to values, so you must tell Rust how long those references will live:

```rust
struct Configurator<'a> {
    cli_args: ArgMatches<'a>,
    root_directory: String
}
```

You must do the same for the `impl` block:

```rust
impl<'a> Configurator<'a> {
    pub fn build() -> Configurator<'a> {
      // ...
    }
}
```

The other issue with your code is that in Rust, you must initialize all fields when instantiating a struct:

```rust
// this doesn't work
let config = Configurator {}

// but this does
let config = Configurator {
  cli_args: cli_args, 
  root_directory: "/home".to_string(),
};
```

Finally, you have to return the `Configurator` from the function:

```rust
pub fn build() -> Configurator<'a> {
    let cli_args = App::new("Rust Web Server")
        .version("0.0.1")
        .author("Blaine Lafreniere <brlafreniere@gmail.com>")
        .about("A simple web server built in rust.")
        .arg(
            Arg::with_name("root_dir")
                .short("r")
                .long("root_dir")
                .value_name("ROOT_DIR")
                .help("Set the root directory that the web server will serve from.")
                .takes_value(true),
        )
        .get_matches();

    return Configurator {
        cli_args: cli_args,
        root_directory: "/home".to_string(),
    };
}
```

Here is a [runnable example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f6f3dd829061c41e35af00fcdcd70ed).

Answer (score 1):

Since you build the `App` using only `'static` strings then the return type of `.arg_matches()` is `ArgMatches<'static>` which you should explicitly state in your `Configurator` struct definition. This is much better than using a generic lifetime parameter like `'a` since it doesn't "infect" your `Configurator` struct with any lifetime annotations. Also, you cannot "partially" initialize structs in Rust, they must be fully initialized, so I've moved the construction of the `Configurator` struct to the bottom of the `build` function when all data is ready.

```rust
use clap::{Arg, App, ArgMatches};

struct Configurator {
    cli_args: ArgMatches<'static>,
    root_directory: String
}

impl Configurator {
    pub fn build(root_directory: String) -> Configurator {
        let cli_args = App::new("Rust Web Server")
            .version("0.0.1")
            .author("Blaine Lafreniere <brlafreniere@gmail.com>")
            .about("A simple web server built in rust.")
            .arg(Arg::with_name("root_dir")
                .short("r")
                .long("root_dir")
                .value_name("ROOT_DIR")
                .help("Set the root directory that the web server will serve from.")
                .takes_value(true))
            .get_matches();
        
        Configurator {
            cli_args,
            root_directory,
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e00ebe799e792748306a85e90623ada)